# Highlight cells that don’t meet the drop down criteria

Tags: excel, vba, validation, dropdown, copy-paste

I have a spreadsheet that has drop-down options and people keep copying and pasting entries that do not fit the drop down options.

I’ve created a VBA that scans a worksheet and an error message appears with the cells where there’s entries that don’t fit the drop down option. I just need it to actually highlight in yellow the cells that need to be changed so they can be located easily. Please can someone help?

This is my current VBA:

```
Sub TestValidation()
 
Dim myRng As Range
Dim ErrorMsg As String
Dim NoErrorMsg As String
Dim FoundCells As String
Dim cell As Range
 
Set myRng = Sheets("Portfolio Tracker").Range("D3:AK5000")
ErrorMsg = "You've entered something in a drop-down box cell that isn't a drop-down box option. Please change"
NoErrorMsg = "No cells that do not abide to validation"
FoundCells = ""
For Each cell In myRng
   If Not cell.Validation.Value Then
      FoundCells = FoundCells & "," & cell.Address
   End If
   Next cell
If Len(FoundCells) >= 1 Then
   MsgBox ErrorMsg & Right(FoundCells, Len(FoundCells) - 1)
Else
   MsgBox NoErrorMsg
End If
Set myRng = Nothing
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not control the cells with data validation? ie range of numbers or integer or in a list of words etc.

Comment: @SolarMike because data validation ignores pasted values :)

Comment: @SolarMike, thank you for your response. People are copying and pasting information from one spreadsheet to another. Will data validation work in this instance? What's currently happening is that it allows them to paste over the cells irrespective of it is meeting a drop-down option or not.

Comment: @allthem I have just been testing, based on the comment answering mine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event and if someone pastes invalid values it will undo the pasting and throw a message.

Note that you will need to use DataValidation in addition with this procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RevertChanges As Boolean
    
    Const WatchedRange As String = "D3:AK5000"
    
    On Error GoTo ENABLE_EVENTS  ' in case of error enable events
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    
    Dim AffectedCells As Range
    Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Me.Range(WatchedRange))
    
    If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
        Dim ValidationType As Variant
        ValidationType = AffectedCells(1).Validation.Type
        
        If Not IsEmpty(ValidationType) Then
            Dim Cell As Range
            For Each Cell In AffectedCells
                If Cell.Value <> "" Then
                    If Not Cell.Validation.Value Then
                        RevertChanges = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next Cell
        Else
            RevertChanges = True
        End If
        
        If RevertChanges Then
            MsgBox "Invalid values were pasted. Undo pasting.", vbCritical, "Computer Says No"
            Application.Undo
        End If
    End If
    
ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Alternatively just use data validation for the drop downs and then use `Sheets("Portfolio Tracker").CircleInvalid` to circle the invalid values:

[image]

Comment: @PEH, whilst I love your response, particularly the computer says no part (made me laugh so thank you for that), I was hoping the VBA would be able to highlight the incorrect cells in the spreadsheet rather than confirm the location in the error message.

Comment: @allthem Well, you can just use Datavalidation for the drop downs and then just run `Sheets("Portfolio Tracker").CircleInvalid` and it will circle the invalid ones. If you run it with the `Worksheet_Change` event it even does it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to color the invalid cells you can add `cell.Interior.Color = 65535` in the first if condition.

```
   If Not cell.Validation.Value Then
        cell.Interior.Color = 65535
        FoundCells = FoundCells & "," & cell.Address
   End If
```

Comment: that worked an absolute treat, thank you so much!!

Comment: why so complicated you can just run `Sheets("Portfolio Tracker").CircleInvalid` to circle them, the circle will even disappear automatically if you select a valid value.

Comment: Was just on point of the request, I was not familiar with .CircleInvalid until now, thank you!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I've just fixed it using your suggestion. Thank you so much for that.